# React.js parent component do not render child components correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS, but already got some problem I cannot resolve...

I have React component called Tree. This component must receive array of some data. Every element in this array must be rendered as a special child component called Department.

At the beginning, Tree has state {departments: []}, so, tree must be empty and it is. But then I change Tree's state, I set new array at departments, I see no child elements.

And the point is, that tree's state really updates, and function "render" is really called, and when I run thru departments, I get the right number of iterations in my cycle (checked with console.log). But still no child element appears.

My code works, I tried to render tree component with fixed departments and set this state in the constructor as initial state. Tree and child components worked fine.

So, I cannot imagine, what might be wrong.

Here is my code, my class Tree

```
class Tree extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            departments: []
        }
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('GET', startAdress + '/tutors' + '/getAll', true);
       xhr.send();
       var tree = this;
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
           if (xhr.status != 200) {
               alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
           } else {
               var newDepts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
               if (Array.isArray(newDepts.content)) {
                   tree.setState({
                       departments: newDepts.content
                   });
               }
           }
       };
   }

   render() {
       var a = this;
       console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.departments));
       console.log(this.state.departments.length);
       return ( <div className={"Tree"}>
           {
               this.state.departments.forEach(function (department) {
                   console.log("creating branches");
                   return (
                       <Department key={department.name} department={department} />
                   );}
               ) }
           </div> )
   }
}
```

And here is my child component Department. It uses another component, called TreeLine, but I think it is not necessary to put it here.

```
class Department extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log("department " + JSON.stringify(this.props.department));
        return (
            <div className={'Department'}>
                <TreeLine key={this.props.department.name } classNamePostfix={"Dep"}
                item={this.props.department} />
                {this.props.department.items.forEach(function (item) {
                             return (
                                 <TreeLine key={item.name} classNamePostfix={"Item"}  item={item} />
                            )})
                 }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `console.log()` is a handy tool for outputting data which seems to be returning unexpected behavior. In Department class, try switching the forEach to map, as I don't think forEach returns anything. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I would not use console log, that is a poor approach, use F12 dev tools and add in break points into the code, or add "debugger" in your code, that will allow you to step through and over code. Also, there's a great Chrome plugin for React.

Comment: you should try to use axios for your http requests, and redux to handle your application state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.forEach()` you should be using `.map()`.

`forEach` goes through every element of the array and does something with it, but nothing is returned by `forEach`, even if the callback returns something. On the other hand, `map` creates a new array with what is being returned in the callback function as an element in that new array.

```
const a = [1,2,3].forEach((i) => {return <span>{i}</span>})
// a = undefined
const b = [1,2,3].map((i) => {return <span>{i}</span>})
// b = [<span>1</span>, <span>2</span>, <span>3</span>]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now) I think, I need to read about js again)